# Divide int elements in array into 2 equal or almost equal suma

Tags: java

The problem is the following:
We have an array of integers... we need to check if it can be partitioned into 2 arrays where the sum of elements for the two arrays is the same ... if the totals can't be equal then we partition the array into 2 where the totals are as equal/near as possible.

This is the part where it checks if it can be partitioned with equal sums:

```
public boolean canPartition(int[] num) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++)
            sum += num[i];

        // if 'sum' is a an odd number, we can't have two subsets with equal sum
        if(sum % 2 != 0)
            return false;

        return this.canPartitionRecursive(num, sum/2, 0);
    }

    private boolean canPartitionRecursive(int[] num, int sum, int currentIndex) {
        // base check
        if (sum == 0)
            return true;

        if(num.length == 0 || currentIndex >= num.length)
            return false;

        // recursive call after choosing the number at the currentIndex
        // if the number at currentIndex exceeds the sum, we shouldn't process this
        if( num[currentIndex] <= sum ) {
            if(canPartitionRecursive(num, sum - num[currentIndex], currentIndex + 1))
                return true;
        }

        // recursive call after excluding the number at the currentIndex
        return canPartitionRecursive(num, sum, currentIndex + 1);
    }
```

if this returns true then sum1= sum2= sum/2

if it returns false then run the following:

Arrays.sort(itemsWeight);

```
        int sum1 = 0;
        int sum2 = 0;
        for (int j = numOfItems - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

            if (sum1 < sum2) {
                sum1 += itemsWeight[j];
            } else {
                sum2 += itemsWeight[j];
            }
           
        }
```

this solution does not seem to work with all inputs and I cant figure out why... can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a boolean problem, as a near solution would also do.

- The problem reads as calculate half of the sum: HALF. (The total sum may be odd, so integral half.)
- Then pick elements for the first array with a sum <= HALF, sum maximal.
- The second array is formed by the remaining elements.

You have to keep the currently *best* solution:

- Array [], sum 0
- The possible candidates: all the array

And then do your recursion. Starting sorted is a good idea.

Happy programming.